# How to show the number in R lattice package

Tags: r, lattice

We use R 4.0.5, lattice 0.20-38, MacOS 10.14.5.

```
library("lattice")
xyplot(Ozone ~ Temp | Month,
layout=c(1,5),
data=airquality
)
```

We got the below figure based on this code.
[image]

We want to change the name of each figure "Month" to the number of Month. The composite (damy) image is shown below. How should we do?

[image]

Comment: I would appreciate it if you answer two more variations (1) If we want to Month label "from 5 to 9," how should I do? (2) If we want to Month label "from 0 to 4," how should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `month` column to factor.

```
library(lattice)

lattice::xyplot(Ozone ~ Temp | Month,
       layout=c(1,5),
       data = transform(airquality, Month = factor(match(Month, unique(Month))))
)
```

[image]

Note that in data `Month` value is from 5 to 9 but since you want labels from 1 to 5 we use `match` and `unique` to get that.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Can I ask one more question?
(1) If we want to Month label "from 5 to 9," how should I do? (2) If we want to Month label "from 0 to 1," how should I do?

Comment: Sorry I had one mistake.  (2) If we want to Month label "from 0 to 4," how should I do?

Comment: @rrkk For 5-9 you can just use `data = transform(airquality, Month = factor(Month))`. For 0-4 use `data = transform(airquality, Month = factor(match(Month, unique(Month)) -1))`

Comment: I appreciated your kind response! Your idea solved my questions.